# How to open a data:image/png;base64 URL in the browser from a Firefox OS app?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I need to open a data:image/png;base64 URL in the default browser in Firefox OS.
The relevant portions of the code:
HTML:

```
<img src="img/Link.png" onclick="generateLink()"/>
<a href="#" id="link" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("link").href=document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].toDataURL();
```

The code works in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript you have the expression:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')
```

but you don't have any canvas elements in your HTML code.

What you should be doing is using canvas' [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage%28%29) calls to place the bitmap into a canvas 2D context, then calling toDataURL on the canvas.

Also, why does the user have to touch the image first to generate the link?  Why not create the data URL in one step?

Comment: The canvas element is auto-generated. That is why I have not mentioned it. You are going in the wrong direction.